# pageslts: Different last-pages with consecutive use of same \pagenumbering-style

Tags: page-numbering, pageslts

Please have a look at this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pageslts}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage~of \lastpages{arabic}{1}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]

\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve is that for the first four pages it says "of 4" and for the rest "of 5", but it does either say "of 9" or "of 5" for the whole document.

Even after reading the documentation for "pageslts" I did not find an example for how to do that when the pagenumbering-style does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as follows, using the `atbegshi` and `zref` packages. The code given below correctly handles:

- any number of divisions (I had to find a word that is distinct from “chapter” and “part” to avoid confusion, so this is it: “division”);
- one-sided as well as two-sided documents;
- funky definitions of `\thepage`, including changing it after `\newDivision`. In particular, as shown in the examples below, you may use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for a given division of your document, `\pagenumbering{roman}` for another one, `\pagenumbering{Alph}` for a third one, etc.
- pending floats when `\end{document}` is reached.

So, as you guessed, your document is divided into one or more *divisions* and you have to call `\newDivision` whenever you want to start a new one. Among other things, `\newDivision` does `\cleardoublepage` and resets the page number to 1, so you don't need to do these things yourself.

**Three compilation runs are required** (but don't worry, LaTeX warns you whenever you need to recompile). Two runs are needed in order to get the `\thepage` (formatted page number) of the last page of the document and store it in an internal label used by my code, and one more to have `fancyhdr` read the correct value from this internal label and use it in the headers of the last division (there is one such internal label for each division: it gives the `\thepage` value of the last page of the corresponding division). Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[lastpage]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{myDivision}
\setcounter{myDivision}{0}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \protected@xdef\mydiv@lastpage{\thepage}%
}

\newcommand{\newDivision}{%
  % This is the correct thing to do because in one-sided documents,
  % \cleardoublepage is equivalent to \clearpage.
  \cleardoublepage
  \let\@currentlabel\mydiv@lastpage
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{\label{my@division-\number\value{myDivision}}}%
  \stepcounter{myDivision}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}

% This correctly handles the case of pending floats at \end{document} time
\AtEndDocument{%
  \zref@refused{LastPage}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\zref@extract{LastPage}{page}}%
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{\label{my@division-\number\value{myDivision}}}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage~of~\ref{my@division-\number\value{myDivision}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1-18]

\newDivision

\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[1-24]

\newDivision

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

If you compile this document as I said (i.e., three times), you'll obtain this:

[image: oneside screenshot]

If you replace the `\documentclass{article}` line with `\documentclass[twoside]{article}`, this will change the opening page of the third division. Indeed, in one-sided mode, the third division of this sample document started on page 10, which is even. By convention, this is not acceptable in two-sided mode, therefore the `\cleardoublepage` done by `\newDivision` will make the third division start on the next odd page, which is page 11 (these are of course absolute page numbers of the whole document, starting from 1—not the printed page numbers in headers). So, here is the result in `twoside` mode:

[image: twoside screenshot]

Comment: Thank You.
Although it is a bit more complicated than I anticipated, it's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm very happy to hear that. Getting these things right is tricky (especially the last page), and I doubt you'll find something correct that is significantly shorter (well, probably some of the wizards here could prove me wrong, but I doubt they could manage to make it *really* shorter). :-)